# OneDrive /me Error: InvalidAuthenticationToken

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am using the Code flow ... with scope of "onedrive.readonly onedrive.appfolder"
I get the code, then the token, and when I try to get the information about the user:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me

In java I set the following headers to the request:

```
uc.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
uc.setRequestProperty("Authorization", String.format("Bearer %s", mSessionInfo.BearerToken));
```

I get the error:

> {   "error": {
>       "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
>       "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 8004920A",
>       "innerError": {
>         "request-id": "b8959569-efd0-4575-947e-c8835f8fef93",
>         "date": "2018-08-29T15:46:53"
>       }   } }

What does this error mean ? How to proceed ?

Answer (score 0):

The response actually indicates that the access token was not successfully generated or passed to the graph endpoint. Microsoft Graph couldn't parse it as a JWT token and thus attempted to process it as a Microsoft Account/Live Id compact token, which also failed. Please check the response that you got from the call to login.microsoftonline.com and that the token passed to graph.microsoft.com is a valid JWT token.